# How do I prevent Unity from displaying my photos from Facebook and Google+?

Tags: 12.10, unity, facebook, google-plus

The title pretty much says it all. I don't want to see my "friends'" pictures, if i don't want to.

I tried to install unity-next following a [tutorial from omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-run-unity-next-on-your-desktop), I removed all of its dependencies, but something might have gotten by me, that had this feature in it.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10(AMD64).

Comment: I never used that feature but I guess you can got to `System Setting...`->`Online Accounts` and remove those accounts. It als might help to remove `unity-lens-gwibber`. But I'm just guessing here ;-)

Comment: removing `unity-lens-gwibber` did not do anything? But disabling facebook via online account did! Please post your comment in an answer form, and i will accept it!

Comment: Not bad for a wild guess :D Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System Settings...`->`Online Accounts` and disable/remove the accounts for Facebook and/or Google+. This way they cannot be accessed anymore and the photos wont appear.